# Designing a rich API which handles both delete and update

Tags: rest

I am designing a API which will be used to delete and update resorces of same kind.

The current API design is

`/employee/family-members  POST`

body

```
{
    deletedFamilyMembers: [{
        id: 1,
        name  : 'Julia',
        employee: 8,
        dob: '1984-05-21',
        relation: 2,
        dependant: true
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name : 'Dave',
        employee: 8,
        dob: '1971-05-21',
        relation: 1,
        dependant: true
    }],
    familyMembers: [{
        id: 3,
        name  : 'Robert',
        employee: 8,
        dob: '1963-05-21',
        relation: 3,
        dependant: true
    }, {
        employee: 8,
        name  : 'Ivan',
        dob: '1965-05-21',
        relation: 3,
        dependant: true
    }]
}
```

On success the API returns list of saved familyMembers with response status `200`

```
[{
        id: 3,
        name  : 'Robert',
        employee: 8,
        dob: '1963-05-21',
        relation: 3,
        dependant: true
    }, {
        id: 4,
        employee: 8,
        name  : 'Ivan',
        dob: '1965-05-21',
        relation: 3,
        dependant: true
    }]
```

If any of the family-members in deletedFamilyMembers array are referred then the API return error saying
 `Cannot delete as the family member is being referred` with resonse status `409`

Suggest changes required to make it compatible with REST best practices.

Comment: first of all you should use created status code for post (201) [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/201),
and take a look at microsoft rest api guidelines [guidelines](https://github.com/microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/vNext/Guidelines.md)

Comment: It is a rich API performing multiple operations, 201 is not a right choice for this

Comment: No matter how rich api, it’s common recommendation If you create something return 201 status code.Although post should not be used for update or delete, for update you can use http put and for delete httpdelete

Answer (score 0):

```
POST /employee/family-members
```

That's very good for a use case that is expected to modify the representation associated with `GET /employee/family-members`.

My guess is that isn't quite what you are really doing -- the presence of "employee: 8" in the payload suggests that you are not modifying a general employee resource, but rather a resource with semantics specific to a particular employee.

It that's the case, then REST would encourage changing the target-uri to the resource that you are actually modifying.  The motivation is that it allows general-purpose components to update their caches; HTTP has standardized cache invalidation semantics that you can take advantage of.  See [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4).

[407 Proxy Authentication Required](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.2) seems an odd choice of status code for the use case that you describe.  You might be better served by [409 Conflict](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8), or even the pedestrian [403 Forbidden](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3).

Comment: i am returning 409 HttpStatus.Conflict, it was a typo. Thank you for pointing out. Corrected it